# How can I get nyc/istanbul JavaScript coverage from rspec integration tests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, istanbul

I've got a [Ruby on Rails app](https://github.com/WikiEducationFoundation/WikiEduDashboard) with a JavaScript (mostly React) frontend. The suite of `rspec` feature tests exercises a significant portion of the frontend JavaScript code, but I don't have any visibility into that. Meanwhile the JavaScript unit tests — run via `jest` — provide JavaScript coverage mapping.

I would like cumulative JavaScript coverage results from the `rspec` browser-based integration tests, but I haven't found any examples of this. `nyc`, the standard JS coverage library, should be capable of making this happen — probably in combination with `babel-plugin-istanbul`.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not a direct explanation of how to implement this, you can find out how someone else managed to implement having code coverage in a Ruby on Rails . You can see [here](https://blog.shakacode.com/optimized-parallelized-circleci-configuration-for-reactonrails-3489e59ac012) that they use `jest` with `--coverage` flag to get the coverage results.

I think it might be wise to separate out your JavaScript code coverage from your other feature tests, since every tutorial out there appears to lean towards separating these out.

Here's another tutorial just in case the other one isn't quite what you're looking for: https://reactjsnews.com/setting-up-rails-for-react-and-jest

Answer (score 1):

You can use capybara system/feature test to capture JS code coverage with istanbul.

we're doing it with webpack, it probably can be done with the asset pipeline but I have no idea where to start.

In general you need to get istanbul in to your webpack pipeline and then you need to scrape the `__coverage__` variable off of every page before you move to the next page in your tests.

`yarn add istanbul-instrumenter-loader -D`

`yarn add nyc -D`

in config/webpack/development.js - yes, dev, not test - make sure you don't have NODE_ENV === test

```js
if (process.env.CI) {
  environment.loaders.append('istanbul-instrumenter', {
    test: /(\.js)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
      options: { esModules: true },
    },
    enforce: 'post',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  })
}
```

And then you need to scrape those feature/system tests. We're using system tests with rspec - this is the helper we run

spec/support/js_code_coverage_helper.rb

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# ugly hack to get in between the teardown of the browser session to collect the JS info for coverage - have to grab it
# from the rails system test because rspec doesn't expose it and the after block doesn't fire in the right place.
module JsCodeHelpers
  def before_teardown
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def dump_js_coverage
    return if page.driver.class.name == 'Capybara::RackTest::Driver' # HACK
    return unless ENV['CI']

    coverage_report_dir = '.nyc_output'
    FileUtils.mkdir_p coverage_report_dir if ENV['CI']
    page_coverage = page.evaluate_script('JSON.stringify(window.__coverage__);')

    return if page_coverage.blank?

    File.open(Rails.root.join(coverage_report_dir, "system_test_#{Time.current.to_i}.json"), 'w') do |report|
      report.puts page_coverage
    end
  end
end

require 'action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/setup_and_teardown'

ActionDispatch::SystemTesting::TestHelpers::SetupAndTeardown.prepend(JsCodeHelpers)

# another ugly hack to scrape coverage information before any potential element navs us away from the page we're on - if we move to
# another page then we lose the __coverage__ variable. we do end up multi-capturing coverage - that's not important now.
require 'capybara/node/element'
module ClickTaker
  # private method that all the clicks use - this is as close as we can get to the bare browser easily
  def perform_click_action(keys, wait: nil, **options)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def select_option(wait: nil)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def send_keys(*args)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def trigger(event)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def drag_to(node, **options)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def drop(*args)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def execute_script(script, *args)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def evaluate_script(script, *args)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def evaluate_async_script(script, *args)
    dump_js_coverage
    super
  end

  def dump_js_coverage
    return if session.driver.class.name == 'Capybara::RackTest::Driver' # HACK
    return unless ENV['CI']

    coverage_report_dir = '.nyc_output'
    FileUtils.mkdir_p coverage_report_dir if ENV['CI']
    page_coverage = session.evaluate_script('JSON.stringify(window.__coverage__);')

    return if page_coverage.blank?

    File.open(Rails.root.join(coverage_report_dir, "system_test_#{Time.current.to_i}.json"), 'w') do |report|
      report.puts page_coverage
    end
  end
end

Capybara::Node::Element.prepend(ClickTaker)
```

It's a WIP/hack until I figure out a better way to capture everything between page transitions - but it works great.

Note that our config requires CI=true to run - that's simple to remote but `CI=true rspec spec/system` will get you js coverage

Then you can do whatever you need to with the files in .nyc_output

`yarn nyc report`

`yarn nyc merge ./.nyc_output  coverage.json`

The only downside to this is that it shows multiple hits for the same coverage on a line (line count) if it captures a file before going to the next page (all the clicks...) this was better for us as we don't use remote forms for everything - we'd lose anything run on a form if we finished the test on a new page after a submit/post.

Comment: In my project, we ended up recently finding a somewhat similar solution using `JSCover` instead of `nyc`: https://github.com/WikiEducationFoundation/WikiEduDashboard/pull/4131/files

Comment: One trick that might apply to your setup like it did for ours is to use `clear_local_storage: false` for the Capybara Selenium driver. That let us build up coverage across a whole test run without worrying about anything getting reset between page loads.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts Sage! Unfortunately changing clear_local_storage didn't work - we still needed the click overloads.